# Adding and validating a namespaced attribute value using XAttribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I want to programmatically create a "dcterms:type" element with a namespaced attribute and attribute value using XObjects. The target xml is as follows:

```
<metadata
        xmlns="http://example.org/myapp/"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.org/myapp/ http://example.org/myapp/schema.xsd"
        xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
        xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">
    ...
    <dcterms:type xsi:type="dcterms:URI">test</dcterms:type>
    ...
</metadata>
```

I have tried:

```
XNamespace dcterms= XNamespace.Get("http://purl.org/dc/terms/");
XNamespace xsi = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
XNamespace dc = XNamespace.Get("http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/");

XAttribute xsiAttribute = new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi.NamespaceName);
XAttribute dcAttribute = new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "dc", dc.NamespaceName);
XAttribute dcmitypeAttribute = new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "dcterms", dcterms.NamespaceName);
...
XElement typeElement = new XElement(dc + "type", "test");  
XAttribute typeAttribute = new XAttribute(xsi + "type", dcterms + "URI");
typeElement.Add(typeAttribute);
```

But this produces:

```
<dc:type xsi:type="{http://purl.org/dc/terms/}Text">test</dc:type>
```

... which is wrong and, of course, does not validate. I have also tried hard-coding the value:

```
XAttribute typeAttribute = new XAttribute(xsi + "type", @"dcterms:URI");
```

This produces the correct xml, but returns "This is an invalid xsi:type 'http://purl.org/dc/terms/:Text'." when validated via XDocument.Validate().

Ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you have added proper xsd markup in your xml too? See MSDN how validation works: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340331.aspx

Comment: Yes, my namespaces weren't sorted out properly. Thanks for having a look!